# Is Pandas (v 1.1.4) using a deprecated NumPy datetime64 with timezone datatype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Pandas Timestamps are timezone aware, so I can make a DatetimeIndex of Timestamps like

```
import numpy a np
import pandas as pd

pd.date_range('2020-03-08', periods=10, freq='12H', tz='America/Denver')

DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-08 00:00:00-07:00', '2020-03-08 13:00:00-06:00',
               '2020-03-09 01:00:00-06:00', '2020-03-09 13:00:00-06:00',
               '2020-03-10 01:00:00-06:00', '2020-03-10 13:00:00-06:00',
               '2020-03-11 01:00:00-06:00', '2020-03-11 13:00:00-06:00',
               '2020-03-12 01:00:00-06:00', '2020-03-12 13:00:00-06:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/Denver]', freq='12H')
```

Notice the `dtype='datetime64[ns, America/Denver]'` bit. This implies it's using NumPy's timezone aware datetime type. But wasn't this [deprecated in NumPy 1.11.0](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.11.0-notes.html?highlight=release%20notes)?

> The datetime64 type is now timezone naive.

How does this work then? Can I expect Pandas timestamps to properly support timezones and all the nuances that come with them?

Comment: as I read it, numpy never implemented time zones, only offsets (UTC +/- x). And as I understand, pandas internally uses pytz and dateutil for handling time zones, see [src](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timezones.pyx). My guess would be that they will also implement [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the future since from my experience it's a bit more efficient than pytz/dateutil.

Answer (score 0):

[series-dt-tz_convert.php](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-dt-tz_convert.php) and [series-dt-tz_localize.php](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-dt-tz_localize.php) seems to imply that the time zones being used are not in numpy but rather in the format of one of these three

> str, pytz.timezone, dateutil.tz.tzfile or None

This makes me want to read the source of the pandas code to see what is going on under the hood...